# OpenLayers 3: "goog is not defined"

Tags: openlayers

First time using OpenLayers.  I am getting an error "goog is not defined".  Here are the steps I performed:

1. Downloaded and unzipped v3.0.0-gamma.4
2. It created the following directory structure:

   - apidoc
   - build
   - closure-library
   - css
   - doc
   - examples
   - ol
   - resources
3. I proceed to create a file called ol3.html and place it in the examples folder shown above.  Here is the code of that file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="../ol/ol/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuestOpenAerial()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View2D({
          center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

4. When I load up the page, I get the error "goog is not defined".  I can see that it finds the local **ol.js** file but it give the error "goog is not defined".
5. If I switch this line:

   `<script src="../ol/ol/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

   To this:

   `<script src="http://ol3js.org/en/v3.0.0-beta.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Then everything is fine and I can see the map. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take the ol.js file from the build directory. That means "../build/ol.js".

There is a "ol-debug.js" file, too, which contains a uncompressed version of ol3.

Comment: Using from file from the build directory fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This phenomenon is caused by the coding style of OpenLayers 3. OL3 is built with Google's [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/), which eases the development process, and offers a very good compression rate to the final code (maybe there are some other advantages which I don't know about). Closure has modular `goog` classes. The library gets rid of them when the final code is compiled and compressed (i.e. built).

Because of this, there are two ways to use OL3:

- Use the compiled library from the `build` folder, as @Simon Zyx mentioned (faster, recommended for deployment).
- Include the appropriate script files from the Closure Library along with the inbuilt code, e.g. `<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>` (slower, recommended for development and testing).